# Cleaning data which to use (Grep) or (str_extract_all)

Tags: r, regex, string, text-extraction

I need to extract from the dataset all the elements that mention "mean" and "std" which is standard deviation.

example of how it is written in feat, the column 2, the variables.

Goal> I am trying to extract only the elements that have this written.

```
"tBodyAcc-mean()-Z"
"tBodyAcc-std()-X"

feat<-read.table("features.txt")
```

I assumed that using

```
grep("mean"&"std",feat[,2])
```

would work

But does not work, I have this error:

```
 "operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types"
```

I found someone who has used this:

```
meansd<-grep("-(mean|std)\\(\\)",feat[,2])
```

It worked fine but I do not understand the meaning of the backlashes.

I don't understand what it exactly means and I don't want to use it.

Comment: Please show some reproducible example

Comment: try `grep('mean|std', feat[,2])` or more complex regex...

Comment: Please learn how to [format your question text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: drmariod it worked. I just thought that because was a string I had to use the " brackets to say to my vector to find that string and store it.

Comment: regarding backslash: first backslash is escaping the regexp metacharacters '(' and ')' second backslash is escaping the R reserved character '\'

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an [*alternation operator* `|`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in a regex pattern. `grep` allows using literal values (when `fixed=TRUE` is used) or  a regular expression (by default).

Now, you found:

```
meansd<-grep("-(mean|std)\\(\\)",feat[,2])
```

The `-(mean|std)\(\)` regex matches a `-`, then either `mean` or `std` (since `(...)` is a [grouping construct](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that allows enumerating alternatives inside a bigger expression), then `(` and then `)` (these must be escaped with a `\` literal symbol - that is why it is doubled in the R code).

If you think the expression is an overkill, and you only want to find entries with either `std` or `mean` as substrings, you can use a simpler

```
meansd<-grep("mean|std",feat[,2])
```

Here, no grouping construct is necessary since you only have two alternatives in the expression.